Formbuilder and Drupal 7
Questions about FormBuilder and Drupal 7...for those of us who are laggards with upgrading our Drupal.

What is the easiest way to embed a formbuilder form onto a Drupal 7 page?  For Wordpress-based sites we can use shortcodes.  For Drupal 8/9/10 we can use this Afform Block module.  But for Drupal 7 I don't see a way?

Is it possible to restrict access to a FormBuilder form based on Drupal role?

Is it possible to restrict access to a FormBuilder form based on CiviCRM Group membership?


Thank you!
